# CKEditor remove classes from html tags in TYPO3

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

I am using CKEditor in Typo3.When i am writing For example if I hit source and create
  

p class="font12"

 and when i save it.It returns only p not the class. so i need this class should not be removed.I have searched it on google but have not find the solution actually which file to Edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably this is defined in the typoscript of the ext. 
have a look at the TS files of the extension itself, you will have a greater inside of the plugin's setting then googling it.